Weird way of finding an oblique asymptote
Motivation:I JUST learnt about asymptotes, maybe $50$ minutes ago, in my maths class. We were only taught how to find horizontal and vertical ones. But I found this one problem
$$x^3+y^3=3xya$$
This had no vertical or horizontal asymptotes, but it had an oblique one.I couldn't stop myself from doing some weird math to find it

(My seems to be correct) Method:-
As the function is symmetric about $y=x$ line, I thought of making it the new $X$ axis. Similarly $y=-x$ is the Y axis.According to the graph , aill get a nice vertical asymptote then.
Let $X=y-x$,$Y=y+x$
In this form, the function becomes $$Y(Y^2+3X^2)=6a(Y^2-X^2)$$
From here, I get a horizontal asymptote, rather, which gives $Y=-2a$ or $x+y+2a=0$, which is correct, but I wanted a vertical one :(
$\text{Hence}$,I wish to know what is wrong with my imagination

Possibly helpful: Why this method gives an asymptote while being like nonsense, is this a coincidence or some logic below is not discovered AND Find the asymptotes, if any of the Folium of Descartes: $x^3+y^3=3xy$.

If you want $y=x$ to be the $X$ axis (i.e. the line $Y=0$) and $y=-x$ to be the $Y$ axis (the line $X=0$), what you must set is $$Y=y-x\quad\text{and}\quad X=y+x$$ (instead of your $X=y-x$ and $Y=y+x$).
Your asymptote $x+y+2a=0$ will then be defined by $X=-2a$, hence will be vertical.

OHH now I get it, the $X$ axis is $Y=0$. Ah I was being so stupid
